# Highchart - xAxis values are to close

Tags: highcharts

I've a classic line chart with weekly date for x-axis.

But if I put a lot of values, dates at the bottom are not readable (too close).

```
$(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({ 
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval:  7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        type: 'datetime', 
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%d/%m/%Y}',
            rotation: -45,
            y: 30,
            align: 'center'
        } 
    }, 
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 4, 4),
            pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
    },

    series: [{ 
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mf9Eg/

Do you know if it's possible to have a intelligent distribution of these values? When they are too close, just display one on two for example.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mf9Eg/3/ I update it here. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not realy. I can have an undetermined amount of value and it's not just a size and rotation problem. If you copie and paste 2 or 3 times the values in data, you will have the problem again. I need highchart doesn't overwrite the label but adjusts the amount displayed.

Comment: See my answer - you are going to need to tell it how many ticks to label. If you leave `tickInterval` empty it will dynamicaly adjust the label intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `step` property of labels.
try code below.

```
labels: {
            format: '{value:%d/%m/%Y}',
            rotation: -45,
            y: 30,
            align: 'center',
            step:3
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I must calculate it by myself. Step will help me. Thanks.

Comment: Problem with this is that on zoom, when you will have more room, the step is still set to 3.  Which means at times you won't even see a single label.  I still upvoted the answer though, the `step` property is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is determine how many data points I have and then adjust the `tickInterval` accordingly. You have it set to a hardcoded value. You will need to find out what works best for you depending on how many data points you have, your alignment/rotation of xAxis labels, and font used on those labels.